# 18.04 Turned off display in Settings-Devices-Screen Display ON/OFF, how to turn on again?

Tags: display, 18.04, system-settings

On a fresh install of 18.04, with laptop and two external monitors, I turned off the laptop display in Settings->Devices->Screen Display using the ON/OFF slider. How do I turn it back on again? Once turned off, it is taken out of the display arrangement. If I remove the laptop from the dock and power-on, it's display works. If I hot plug into the dock again, the two external monitors switch on, but the laptop screen switches off.

Answer (score 0):

You can turn it back on by clicking on your monitor number in the Display menu and selecting the monitor that is turned back off. Screengrab below:
[display monitor selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1oeP.png)

Each monitor has a number. If you go to `Settings > Devices > Screen Display` and find the monitor number that is your primary monitor. Click on the number and it will show you a dropdown menu of all available monitors. Select the one you turned off and turn it back on.

Answer (score 0):

- Go to **Settings**
- Click on **Devices**
- Now you  should have a window like the one displayed [Displays](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vqtsd.png)
- Then click on the **display button** (below the Display Arrangement section -- in my case it is 'Dell 22"')
- You will get a menu listing of all your displays. You can then select the display you want to **enable** and **turn on the display**.