# 18.04 Built In Display Issue

Tags: gnome, multiple-monitors, display, 18.04, xrandr

I'm having an issue with Ubuntu 18.04, everything was working correctly 2 days ago, but I have just connected my laptop to some external displays and my built-in screen will not turn on.

I can see the screen in Gnome's display settings but I am unable to change the status to enabled/disabled.

[Options displaying correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4L4cr.png)

Using `xrandr -q` gives me:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3840 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
eDP-1 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 193mm
   1920x1080     60.01*+  60.01    59.97    59.96    59.93  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1600x900      59.99    59.94    59.95    59.82  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1400x900      59.96    59.88  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1440x810      60.00    59.97  
   1368x768      59.88    59.85  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x800      59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
   960x600       59.93    60.00  
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   800x450       59.95    59.82  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   700x450       59.96    59.88  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x405       59.51    58.99  
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   640x400       59.88    59.98  
   576x432       60.06  
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
   512x384       60.00  
   512x288       60.00    59.92  
   480x270       59.63    59.82  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   432x243       59.92    59.57  
   320x240       60.05  
   360x202       59.51    59.13  
   320x180       59.84    59.32  
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2-1 connected 1920x1080+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 476mm x 267mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  50.00    59.94  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1600x900      75.00    60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    70.00    60.02  
   1440x900      59.90  
   1366x768      59.79  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
DP-2-2 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 476mm x 267mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  50.00    59.94  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1600x900      75.00    60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    70.00    60.02  
   1440x900      59.90  
   1366x768      59.79  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
DP-2-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Attempting to enable the screen via xrandr (`xrandr --output eDP-1 --auto`) yields the below:

[Screens showing as mirrored](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PdLGT.jpg)

To me it looks like the screen is now enabled but has also become a mirrored display of screen 2, hence the "1 2".

System info:

```
OS: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS x86_64
Host: ThinkPad T580
Kernel: 4.15.0-22-generic
Resolution: 1920x1080, 1920x1080, 1920x1080
DE: GNOME 3.28.1
WM: GNOME Shell
CPU: Intel i5-8250U (8) @ 3.400GHz
GPU: Intel UHD Graphics 620
Memory: 2517MiB / 7477MiB
```

If anybody could help or point me in the right direction that would be a great help.

If you need any more info then just ask.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Open **Settings** > **Devices** > **Displays**, you will find all the options there.
[image]

In the part where the two screens are numbered, you can adjust which one you want to be the primary display by sliding the screens over each other with your mouse cursor.

**Join Displays** will allow you to use multiple displays at the same time.
**Mirror** will display the same thing in multiple displays.
**Single display** will allow you to use just one display.

Comment: I do not seem to have these options at all. Do you have any non-stock software installed? Many thanks.

Comment: I didn't need any extension to get those options, they came by default with Ubuntu 18.04.
May be it is related to the theme you use? I use Ambiance theme.

Comment: Switched everything back to default, rebooted, still no options.

Comment: Check  [this link](https://askubuntu.com/a/1033948/822295) may be it helps you.

Comment: Thanks, I had a look but i think this might actually be a bios/hardware issue as the built in keyboard is not functioning correctly either. Thanks for your help though. I'm going to try booting off a live usb later to see what happens later today.

Comment: Sorry that this didn't help you.